# How to Fix Run-time Error 424 "Object Required" in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on an Excel project where I am trying to produce certain rows from "Sheet 1" that contains a word called "external" in column C and then copy and paste that row into "Sheet 3"

I understand that there is a thing called "filter" but that is not an option.

This project is for my team at work that wants to be able to extract rows and columns that are shown as "external" and then be able to paste them and other information to another sheet that contains that information.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = "External" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Row.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
End Sub
```

The expected result was to display all rows that contained the word "External" in Sheet 1 Column C into a new sheet and have all its information displayed in Sheet 3.

Excel Worksheet for Reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, declare all your variables. Next, you can try changing `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 3).Value = "External" Then` to `If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Text = "External" Then`. See here:

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim b As Long

    a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To a
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Text = "external" Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
            b = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        End If
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Select
 End Sub
```